# TypeScript const generic not narrowing types as expected

Tags: typescript

In [this TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDYQMIHskFcC2A7AHgEkATKCAD2AjxIGco7gAnASzwHMoAfKLWiADN2EMgF5GLdl178SQkSQB8UMQCgoUUuSo16ktpw2aoAfigBvYyZOsSALi0kA3NZMBfN44tQ7px3IKeKJQ7q7s1MyCcADG0PDIEAQY2PgMlNS0DAkoKbh4ANoAuqqwiLmY+cUqVpoxlWmOeWmudQ14AArseNL+lm4ogsB9AKIUMdjyye10BXi4CBDMRQUARHarRQA0fALCwcrFrSZsHAAWw45jE1hTzXiz8ziLy2sb27vy+6JKR8Zhak8akE-BiwFY6DwUBwcAA1hAckl6g9gLAzqw6IidJl9IilAAKYDlCCOGDozHEgCUpPJWNqUGYEGAWGYUKJiVcQJBeDBEKhMPh9wIyKYUHu2L02WJ9wJ9VSeCa7WpYva-U0jOZrKgcvynLUahFqJ1+AAjKUBWh2vifHZHKs8HAcBBVqFKa5Ddr2gAmc1wy3y63uN0GyGigpwHYIEoSC2I63GY0PRwFRMmnaJr3bBPtLp4HqcbxQQbAZOrYDkgC0dDO6CwSBIFeirCQm1CW0BlIAdIm6K4gA):

```
type TableColumn<Id extends string | undefined = string | undefined> =
  Id extends string
    ? {
        id: Id;
      }
    : { id?: undefined };
interface Table<Columns extends TableColumn[] = TableColumn[]> {
  columns: Columns;
  columnPinning?: {
    left?: Exclude<Columns[number]["id"], undefined>[];
    right?: Exclude<Columns[number]["id"], undefined>[];
  };
}

function makeTable<const ThisTable extends Table>(table: ThisTable): ThisTable {
  return table;
}

function makeColumn<const Column extends TableColumn>(column: Column): Column {
  return column;
}

const column1 = makeColumn({ id: "name" });
const column2 = makeColumn({});
const [a, b] = makeTable({
  columns: [column1, column2],
  columnPinning: { left: ["this-should-fail"] },
}).columns;
```

I expected the `makeTable` function to narrow down the types of the columns I instantiated the call with, thanks to the `const` generic; but it seems to not actually be narrowing down. Am I misusing const generics here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version, it will be a complex challenge for the compiler to infer the correct type.

You can accept a generic parameter for the columns, not for the table, and it should work for your case:

```
interface Table<Columns extends readonly TableColumn[] = TableColumn[]> {
  columns: Columns;
  columnPinning?: {
    left?: Exclude<Columns[number]["id"], undefined>[];
    right?: Exclude<Columns[number]["id"], undefined>[];
  };
}

function makeTable<const Columns extends readonly TableColumn[]>(table: Table<Columns>): Table<Columns> {
  return table;
}
```

Make sure to add `readonly`, because *const type parameters* turns everything into `readonly`.

Testing:

```
// readonly [{
//     readonly id: "name";
// }, {}]
const arr = makeTable({
  columns: [column1, column2],
  columnPinning: { left: ["this-should-fail"] },
}).columns;
```

Looks good!

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDYQMIHskFcC2A7AHgEkATKCAD2AjxIGco7gAnASzwHMoAfKLWiADN2EMgF5GLdl178SQkSQB8UMQCgoUUuSo16ktpw2aoAfigBvYyZOsSALi0kA3NZMBfN44tQ7px3IKeKJQ7q7s1MyCcADG0PDIEAQY2PgMlNS0DMwQcCToeEggsIgoKbh4ANoAuqolieX4NSpWmjGYFXSOjXh0rm0d+AAK7HjS-pZuKILAEwCiFDHY8smDvZV4uAgQzNWVAER2+9UANHwCwsHKNf0mbBwAFrOOC0tYKz10G1s7e4ckxzOgUuoiUN2MYTUnjUgn4MWArAKUBwcAA1hAEigCO1esAoJ8dJl9Dk8gUivUymtmgAKYClCCOTFJT5KACUjPpq1SvRaxhywCwzDwUDpiVc0NheHhiOFKPRPWxBSY+LWhL0DCZPSU1Pa3O6a3ZKu5k00-MFwt1FXFajUOOVlvwAEY6nK0GtqT47I59ng4DgIPtQqzXHa8Q68AAmF1ot3cj3uYNqAD0SagJPyhWKlSsKZsadyGfJXqgPr9AdcufcZws7mqtqVeLgzGY0fRTI9xnDXSglXDjrO4Yjp07axGeDGnG8UGmwEcB2AD1YdAAtHQHugsEgSMvoqwkMdQicoayAHRd1xAA)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I guess it was a combo of `readonly` missing and also making the generic be on `Table` instead of `TableColumn[]`.